# VBA WORD looping trought sentences and lines of senteces

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

Is that even possible?

**EDIT: explain my self, and thinking in another aproach**

I can loop trough letters, words and paragraphs, but not thought what I suppose should be sentences, and neither I can find any reference for lines.

As an image worth like a thousand words, I attach a picture to explain myself:

- squared on black an example of text
- squared on green what I success with the code bellow
- squared in red, what I can figure out how to do

[example of sentences coloured as mention, image as link as it is my first post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBoUc.png)

My purpose, is to highlight/mark/colour out those lines that do not fit in a single page width, as example squared in yellow. But not sure how should do event I can not achieve the easy ones.

Any help?
(been searching here and other places for like couple of hours without success)

```
If False Then   ' Cool, letter by letter
    With ActiveDocument
                     For i = 1 To .Characters.Count
                                  .Characters(i).Font.Color = Int(Rnd * 1048576)
                            Next
                    End With
    End If
                       
                    
                    
If False Then  ' Cool, word by word
    With ActiveDocument
                     For i = 1 To .Words.Count
                                  .Words(i).Font.Color = Int(Rnd * 1048576)
                            Next
                    End With
    End If



If False Then  ' :-(  same as paragraph
    With ActiveDocument
                     For i = 1 To .Sentences.Count
                                  .Sentences(i).Font.Color = Int(Rnd * 1048576)
                             Next
                  End With
   End If
    

If True Then ' Cool, paragraph by paragraph
    With ActiveDocument
                     For i = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
                                  .Paragraphs(i).Range.Sentences(1).Font.Color = Int(Rnd * 1048576)
                             Next
                   End With
    End If
```

**NOTE + ADDs : explain my self, and thinking in another aproach**

As some staid bellow, I explain myself, the overall purpose ids to identify “text lines that do not fit in one printing line”. It has something to do with writing poetry, if interested.
I guess I could also try to “locate each character” on the printing line, identify the “line-brake” character (that Word do not take into account to brake sentences), and color manually word by word / letter by letter.
But I neither have found on the character object, a property referring to the position in the printing view.

Comment: Sentences are not Word VBA objects. Lines even less so, since a "line" depends on a particular display of text that can easily change, say, if the font changes. It will help if you state the overall goal you are trying to reach, as your assumptions of how to reach that goal may be flawed.

Comment: «Sentences are not Word VBA objects.» Word VBA has a sentences property, but it has little in common with a grammatical sentence. For example, consider the following: *Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.* For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.

Comment: @JohnKorchok, yes, I know this depend on the display setting, paper size, font size, etc... true, but that means it is not accesible from VBA at all ?

Comment: @macropod thanks also, so whats a sentence on word?, each "simple sentence", simialr to those separated fwith semicolons, dots, or other puntiaction marks?

Comment: the overall reach, is as stayed in last picture, to identify "sentences" that do not fit on the printing line (it has to do with writing poetry, if curios)

Comment: Test it for yourself with a selection or MsgBox loop on the test sentence I posted...

Comment: If you check character by character using Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage), you can determine when a line of text ends and a new one begins.

Answer (score 0):

May be possible to optimize, but this works !!,, (thanks John Korchok)

```
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    first_word_of_paragraph = True
    
    For Each w In p.Range.Words
        If first_word_of_paragraph = True Then
            first_word_of_paragraph = False
            actual_line_vertical_start = w.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
            End If
        
        If first_word_of_sentence = True Then
            first_word_of_sentence = False
            actual_line_vertical_start = w.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
            End If
            
        If w.Text = "" Then
            first_word_of_sentence = True
            End If
            
        If actual_line_vertical_start <> w.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) Then
            w.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
            End If
```